# Using OpenMP when writing a library

Tags: c, concurrency, openmp, static-libraries

When developing a statically-linked library, how do I secure code accessing shared data against data-races using OpenMP?

If I simply use `#pragma omp critical` on sections I need to run sequentially, am I going to be fine if the library's client uses a different implementation of threads, such as pthreads? Is a critical section compiled into the library as a mutex?

Comment: Maybe too general a question.  On most OS which provide pthreads, OpenMP is based on pthreads, so there is a good chance of doing what you ask.  On Windows, typically both pthreads and OpenMP are based on Windows threads.

Comment: I can't very well make the question more concrete, since I have no idea what environments will the library be used in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [latest OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf), it states that `critical` ensures that only one thread from a "contention group" executes the block at a time. The way I read it, the definition of the contention group only covers OpenMP threads. So, technically, an OpenMP implementation could be written in a way that `critical` does not work with other threading libraries.

Comment: I noticed that as well, which led me to ask. I'm not versed in concurrency well enough to be sure if it is or isn't safe and I'd really like to avoid the code blowing up.

Comment: Since you mentioned you don't have control over the execution environment, you should probably avoid this solution. On the other hand, the most likely implementation of the critical section would be some kind of lock with external linkage named like the critical section. This would work for you. But some alternative or future OpenMP implementation could implement the cricial section in a way that breaks your code.

Comment: Well, what a predicament. I'll accept your answer so we can get this over with. Thanks for your time, you gave me something to think about.